# Using mybatis to map multiple tables to a single collection

Tags: java, xml, mybatis

I have the following POJO which I want mybatis to map my database entries to:

```
public class TestCase {

    private List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I have 10 filter implementations, which all implement the `Filter` interface.

```
public interface Filter {
    boolean isExcluded();
}
```

All 10 filter implementations have 10 associated tables. The tables do **not** have the same columns except for the relation to the `testcase` table.

```
public class SomeFilter implements Filter {

    // Some implementation of Filter

}
```

In the XML mapper I join the 10 tables on the `testcase` table. I can then use 10 different `<resultMap>` tags to map each filter to a its respectful field in the `TestCase` class.

```
private List<Filter> myFilterA;
private List<Filter> myFilterB;
private List<Filter> myFilterC;
```

However, I want to map **all** of them to a **single** field, which is `List<Filter> filters`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but to map the results into a single `List`, you need to concatenate the results into a single result set and use `<discriminator />`.

Assuming two filter tables for example:

```sql
create table filter_a (
  testcase_id int,
  foo varchar(20)
);

create table filter_b (
  testcase_id int,
  bar int
);
```

The mapper would look as follows.

```xml
<resultMap type="TestCase" id="testCaseRM">
  <id column="testcase_id" />
  <collection property="filters" resultMap="filterRM" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="java.lang.Object" id="filterRM">
  <id column="filter_name" />
  <discriminator javaType="string" column="filter_name">
    <case value="a" resultType="FilterA">
      <result column="foo" property="foo" />
    </case>
    <case value="b" resultType="FilterB">
      <result column="bar" property="bar" />
    </case>
  </discriminator>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectAll" resultMap="testCaseRM">
  select testcase_id, 'a' filter_name, foo, null bar from filter_a
  union all
  select testcase_id, 'b' filter_name, null foo, bar from filter_b
</select>
```

Note that I added `filter_name` to the query to identify the filter type of each row.

With this approach, the query could get messy because of `UNION`.
It might be better to execute 10 separate SELECTs and build `TestCase`s manually in a default method or service layer.